# How to book a hotel room with V Pay Card

Tags: bookings, payment-cards

I have a V Pay card from a German Bank and wanted to go spend some day in Belgium, I found a good hotel and put all my informations but when it came to the credit card, I only found American Express, Visa and Mastercard. I put Visa because V pay is from Visa and the expiration date and I put the card number, which is 0/xxxxxxxxx I mean 9 digits after the slash, and it says it's invalid. So what to do ?

Comment: It seems like this hotel simply doesn't accept V Pay.  It's not compatible with the regular Visa system.  You'd have to ask your bank for a different card.  Anyway, info I found suggests that V Pay cards can only be used with the chip and PIN (the card number alone is not valid for purchases), so at minimum you'd need a card reader for your computer.  It also appears that some banks just don't support their use for online purchases at all.

Answer (score 10):

V Pay cards can't be used for card not present transactions (i.e. online). Additionally, German banks don't print the V Pay card number on those cards (it would be of no use for you anyway). The number printed on the card is the number of the account behind your card and sometimes some bank-internal card number.

Even German bank cards (Girocard) co-badged with Maestro can't be used online even if the website offers Maestro as banks simply don't support that.

There are a few German banks offering free debit cards that can be processed via the Visa or MasterCard network (not every such card is a credit card unlike what many people think). My advise would be to take your business to them.